# Drawing Venn diagrams - what is the best approach?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I construct a Venn diagram using a specific set formula? What are the steps involved?

Here is an example:
$(A-C) \cap (C-B)$

Comment: draw 2 Venn diagrams on transparencies

Comment: This should be a null set. $(A-C)$ has elements that are not in $C$. $(C-B)$ has elements in $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always start with the same diagram (for questions involving $3$ sets). Draw three circles which represent sets $A,B,C$ which intersect each other and form a total of $8$ regions (including the outside, which is $(A\cup B\cup C)'$).

[image]

Then you locate the region described by what you're after - $(A-C)\cap(C-B)$. First mark regions $A-C$ and $C-B$. Then mark their intersection (which is empty as pointed out in the comments - so there is no region to mark in this case).

Comment: Ah. I get it. Thanks so much Shuri and sorry for the silly question - just starting with Discrete mathematics and getting to know it all haha. Thanks again : )